# How do I customize the positioning of Wordpress widgets?

Tags: widgets

I want to create new sidebars, footers, etc. where I'll be able to move widgets. Can I try just try to edit the main CSS file to accomplish this or is it more complicated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linda, I actually answered a question very similar to this earlier today. See the following:

[Display specific widgets in different area's around the page](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/25431/display-specific-widgets-in-different-areas-around-the-page/25436#25436)

It's not overly difficult, and opens up a lot of possibilities.

Comment: No problem Linda! Go ahead and mark it as solved if it worked for you, so that others can benefit from it also.